# return a single string value from a Stored procedure without using the Output parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

How to return a single string value from a Stored procedure without using the Output parameters in the SP.

Is this possible ?

The single string value returned by the SP would contain the Sucess or failure message with reason for the failure as well.

How can do this ?

Comment: `SELECT 'Success, it worked'` right at the end?

Comment: @ta.speot.is you should make that an answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this at the end of the sp:

```
IF (SomeCondtion)
BEGIN
   SELECT 'Success'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT 'No success'
END
```

In this link you can find other methods that suit your needs http://www.sqlteam.com/article/stored-procedures-returning-data

Comment: But we have to return the String not just selecting the string

Comment: @user1316031 - Stored procedures are not like functions. They can only [`return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) integers. If you need to return a sting, it must be part of a resultset or an `OUT` variable.